# Algolia Instantsearch: filter by specific facet

Tags: javascript, search, facet, algolia

I'm currently struggling with a multi-language page where we are using Algolia Instantsearch to find apartments for long and short stays.

There are currently 3 facets in our index:

[image]

What I want to archive is that only "Top Cities" and "Cities" will be searchable. I need this behavior for multiple languages at some point.

That's the code someone at GitHub suggested, but it appears it's not searching properly as no results show up:

```
var search = instantsearch({
    appId: appId,
    apiKey: apiKey,
    indexName: 'AS',
    urlSync: false,
    searchParameters: {
        facetsRefinements: {
            categories: ['Top Cities','Cities']
        }
    }
});
```

In this case I tried to exclude the facet "Houses" but the search returns no results at all.

Anyone here who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Excludes are handled in a specific way by the [algoliasearch-helper](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js) .
Does it work with

```
searchParameters: {
    facetsExcludes: {
        categories: ['Houses']
    }
}
```